# Floating div adds space to left on browser zoom

Tags: html, css, css-float

I tried to re-create this as close as possible, in the dev site when it adds space to left of the sidebar it breaks content and moves it to the bottom of sidebar. What's with this space, it breaks my layout.

HTML:

```
<div id="main-wrapper" class="clearfix">
    <div id="main" class="clearfix">
        <div id="sidebar-first" class="column sidebar">
            <p>Sidebar</p>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="column">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1094px;
}
#sidebar-first {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 15px;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: gray;
}
#content {
  padding: 15px 0 15px 15px;
  width: 280px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Just zoom deep enough to make the space appear. I get this issue on Firefox and Safari. In this JSFiddle example you need to zoom pretty deep to get this issue, but on my dev site it breaks on only 90% zoom on Safari and 75% on Firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/fzj8n4we/

Comment: Why do you care about browser zoom?

Comment: I don't, but some other people do.

Comment: Some other people? Zooming in and out on your browser is something which users should expect to encounter wacky style changes on. These aren't necessarily issues. If you treat these as issues you're going to have huge problems: you'll have to treat people changing their browser font size, cursor, scroll bar and everything else as a potential issue.

Comment: So what you're saying is that its not possible to solve this with that small piece of code example?

Comment: Of course it's possible. I just don't see why you'd ever want to. If you sell someone a car, you don't follow them around removing obstacles in front of them before they crash into them, you trust them with control of said car. If they chose to zoom in and out of your website, that's entirely their decision.

Comment: @midts No offense but who do you know that zooms that far out while browsing a website? especially with text.

Comment: Well it's not my website, it's their website and they chose to not the break the layout when zooming out. And I wrote below that you don't need to zoom out that much on the dev site, it's just this sample that needs zooming out a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css if you need it to stick to the left

```css
    #main-wrapper 
    {
      width: 1094px;
    }
    
    #sidebar-first {
      float: left;
      padding: 15px 0 15px 15px;
      width: 180px;
      background-color: gray;
    }
    #content {
      padding: 15px 0 15px 15px;
      width: 280px;
      float: left;
      background-color: #ccc;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="main-wrapper" class="clearfix">
        <div id="main" class="clearfix">
            <div id="sidebar-first" class="column sidebar">
                <p>Sidebar</p>
            </div>
            <div id="content" class="column">
                <p>Content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Okay try this.

Comment: main-wrapper is main page container which is in the middle of the page with no other divs, that's why it has margin and width. So I think that floating only container will break all that.

Comment: Im working off your example. Put it on the container which holds the divs you want to keep left.